# How to round up the price in wordpress to the nearest value?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using following function to round up the price in wordpress..

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price_product', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price_product', 10, 1);

function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    return ceil( $price );
}
```

The above function round up the prices like
If price Rs 999.85/- to Rs 1000/- 
If price Rs 999.15/- to Rs 1000/-

I want round up the price like below..
If Price Rs 999.55/- to Rs 1000/- 
If the price Rs 999.15/- to Rs 999/-

How to do this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the same by simply using the php `round()` function as like this :

```
function round_price_product( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    return round( $price );
}
```

Hope it works for you.